# navbar changing colour from scrolling and div image to fit with object-fit

Tags: javascript, php, css, navbar

I am starting to write a new navbar but having a problem with the `background colour` and `opacity` and a divs image size. Firstly I want the top navbar background colour to be `transparent` when the page is at the top and unscrolled which I have working and then to change to a solid background colour when scrolled down `72px` which also works but it doesn't change back to transparent when scrolled back up to the top? It should also fade the change in if possbile. Also I would like the div with the image in it to be the full width of the page using object-fit but so far it just covers about `95%`. I would also like to be able put text over the image in the center but think I am using wrong method. I'm pretty new to this as you have probably guessed so any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

**The html code is :**

```
<div class="white">
  <ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <div class="container-fluid main" style="margin-top: px;">
    <img src="images/hero.jpg" class="main" alt="mainbg" width="400" height="300">
    </div>

    </div>
```

**and the css is :**

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1000px;
}
.white{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
z-index: 99999;
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  width:100%;
  height:72px;


}
.white ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.white ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  transition: opacity 0.9s linear
}
.main {
    z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
  filter: blur(0.2px);
    width:100%;
    height:550px;
    object-fit:cover;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* General Demo Style */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
/* @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand); */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo);
/* @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat); */
html { height: 100%; width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;

}

a {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.main {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -o-filter: blur(0.2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0.2px);
  filter: blur(0.2px);

    width:100%;
    height:550px;
    object-fit:cover;

}
```

**and the JS is :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 72) {
        $(".white").css("background" , "#00a4ff");
      }

      else{
          $(".white").css("background");    
      }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, I used the toggleClass and set IDs for the classes and divs i needed to change. Many thanks for the help and hope it can save someone else a little time, worth learning though! The JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('#nav').toggleClass('before10',!(scroll > 10)); // toggle Class ad or remove a class considering the second parameter being true or false
    $('#nav').toggleClass('after10',(scroll > 10));// toggle Class ad or remove a class considering the second parameter being true or false
    $('#number').toggleClass('nav-number',!(scroll > 10)); // toggle Class ad or remove a class considering the second parameter being true or false
    $('#number').toggleClass('nav-number2',(scroll > 10));// toggle Class ad or remove a class considering the second parameter being true or false

  })
})
```

and the CSS is :

```
.before10 {text-decoration: none;backgroundcolor:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);}

.after10 {text-decoration: none;background:#362c6e;color:#ffffff;}

.before10 a:link {text-decoration: none;color:#362c6e;}

.after10 a:link {text-decoration: none;color:#ffffff;}

.after10 a:hover {text-decoration: none;color:#e73972;}

.before10 a:hover {text-decoration: none;color:#e73972;}
```